# Integration and proof

Tags: integration

Use the fact that $f(x)<g(x)$ implies that $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx < \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$ to prove that:

$$e-1 \leq \int_0^1\sqrt{(1+x)} e^x \, dx \leq \sqrt(2) (e-1)$$

Please help with this computation - don't know how to simplify things to get a noticeable answer.

Comment: Well, if $0 \le x \le 1$, how big can $\sqrt{1 + x}$ be? How small can it be?

Comment: The smallest value would be 1, and the largest would be $\sqrt{2}$, which are parts of the expressions on the left and right. But I'm not sure where the e-1 would come from, and how do I use the necessary theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bf{Hint}:$
For $0 \leq x \leq 1$,
$$
\sqrt{1} \cdot e^x \leq \sqrt{1+x} \cdot e^x \leq \sqrt{2} \cdot e^x .
$$